# Possible to use Pointiness in GLSL Viewport?

Tags: 3d-view

Is it possible to view a model with Pointiness in the Blender Viewport without rendering?

I'd like to mix Pointiness and Albedo in a Cycles texture paint workflow using the Materials (GLSL) view. When I attempt Pointiness meshes appear as colored as the first Diffuse shader color (Black in this case). Pointiness looks fine in Rendered view.
[image: Mesh Colored Black due to Pointiness]

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes, and how the tutorials I have seen so far ... pointiness are usually only previewable in when viewport is set to "Rendered" mode. You can create a boundary using Ctrl + B and selecting the boundary area to speed up the viewport rendered mode so you don't have to render the whole viewport.

Answer (score 3):

As of today, the pointiness function doesn't do anything in the OpenGL modes. You need to use rendered mode or bake it.

Comment: Thanks JtheNinja. Are there any resources available which list GLSL Viewport limitations for Cycles users?

Comment: Not that I know of, I'm afraid.